# photo shoot not working with camera connected to the computer

Tags: canon-sdk

I am trying to take photos while the camera is connected to the computer. As soon as the camera is connected to to PC the camera changes it's mode to busy. I would like trigger the camera to take picture while it is connected to the computer.

Comment: https://photo.stackexchange.com/ might be a better place for this question. Resolve the "camera busy problem first"

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `EdsSendStatusCommand` function with `kEdsCameraStatusCommand _UIUnLock` to use the camera manually while plugged in. Note that some commands issued with the Canon SDK may lock the camera UI again.